# static variable getting cleared when calling sprintf

Tags: c, static, printf, pic, reentrancy

i am having an issue with a static variable that is showing some odd behavior.  Hopefully someone can help, here is the code:

```
void digitRefresh(void){

static char digitenabled=1;

sprintf(digits, "%d", number+10000);

switch (digitenabled) {
    case 1: digitDecode(digits[1] - 48);
        CATHODE_1 = ENABLE;
        break;
    case 2: digitDecode(digits[2] - 48);
        CATHODE_2 = ENABLE;
        break;
    case 3: digitDecode(digits[3] - 48);
        CATHODE_3 = ENABLE;
        break;
    case 4: digitDecode(digits[4] - 48);
        CATHODE_4 = ENABLE;
        break;
}
delay_ms(DIGIT_DELAY);

disableAllCathodes();
return;
```

}

by the way digits is defined as `char digits[5];`

As you can see i am defining a local static variable, so when this function is called multiple times, i can jump into the different places of the program.

The problem that i shave is in the second line of code.   When the sprintf gets executed the var digitenabled somehow changes its value to zero.   It was one before as you can see in the code, but after the sprint i put a breakpoint and it is a zero for some reason.

If i don't use sprintf by commenting it out, the problem goes away and the variable behaves as expected (not cleared and keeps the value when the function is called again.

Is sprintf doing something wrong ? so the variable is gone ?  any ideas ?

this is on a micro controller PIC16F1847 using XC8 compiler.  Thanks

Comment: How is digits defined? It needs to be char digits[10], not *digits.

Comment: Does the digits has enough memory space to hold all digits?

Comment: char digits[5];  as global.   yes there is not much more in the program, i checked the digits array and it contains what it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 char digits[5];   // from comment -jelipito

 sprintf(digits, "%d", number+10000);  // from question code.
```

Assume the `number` = 0.

The sprintf() is writing "10000" plus a string termination character to `digits`, 6 characters total.  However digits is an array of only five characters.  Writing past the end of an array causes unpredictable results.

Redefine `char digits[5];` to `char digits[50];`, or something that is large enough to hold the output of the sprintf() function.

Another *safety-net* you might consider is to replace `sprint()` with `snprintf()`:

```
 snprintf(digits, sizeof(digits), "%d", number+10000);
```

The snprintf() function will not write beyond the size of the digits array (like sprintf() does).  Rather, it will truncate the output (if necessary) to keep from doing so.

Comment: thanks a lot!  yes that was the problem.   I forgot about the null character from sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is `char digits[5]`. The call to `sprintf` is causing the `digits` variable to exceed its bounds which means undefined behavior that in turn causes funny things to happen!

Instead opt to use the safer call `snprintf` however be aware that `snprintf` is subject to some issues that are made clear via man pages.